# How can I print different colors on different position on circle?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

This is my code but when i set new color with `strokeStyle` on position which I want this

color(new color) override my old color...

I think the problem came from `0 - 90 * Math.PI / 180` because this set starting angle(top) and this overriding every time the circle.But I can't fix this..

Could you help me ?

Something like this..

[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/t8q4vk.png]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          canvas {
            border:1px solid #2C2C2B; /* 1px border around canvas */
          }
        </style>
      </head>
     <body>
        <canvas id="Canvas" width="600" height="250"></canvas>
        <script>
          var i = 0;    
          window.onload = function(){
            setInterval(function(){
             if(i < 6) init();
            },550);

          }
          function init(){
            var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(100,75,50, 0 - 90 * Math.PI / 180,i - 90 * Math.PI/180, false);
            context.lineWidth = 7;
            if(i < 1.5){ context.strokeStyle = 'blue'}
            else if(i > 1.5 && i <= 3){context.strokeStyle = 'red';}
            else if(i > 3 && i <= 4.5){context.strokeStyle = 'blue';}
            else{ context.strokeStyle = 'red';}
            context.stroke();
            i+=0.1;
          }
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to segment the arc in small pieces as each stroke can only have a single color. Also remember to use PI with the angle checks for radians.

### [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/H6F6k/)

**Result:**

[image: Snapshot]

```
var i = 0;
var step = 0.1;
var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

(function init() {
    context.beginPath();

    // use i directly as it is already in radians, draw only a small segment
    context.arc(100, 75, 50, i - 0.5 * Math.PI, i - 0.5 * Math.PI + step);
    context.lineWidth = 7;

    // remember to use PI (it makes it easier at least)
    if (i <= 0.5 * Math.PI) {
        context.strokeStyle = 'blue'
    }
    else if (i > 0.5 * Math.PI && i <= Math.PI) {
        context.strokeStyle = 'red';
    }
    else if (i > Math.PI && i <= 1.5 * Math.PI) {
        context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    }
    else {
        context.strokeStyle = 'red';
    }

    context.stroke();
    
    i += step;

    // check here and use setTimeout
    if (i <= 2 * Math.PI) setTimeout(init, 150);
})();
```

Notice I replaced `setInterval` with `setTimeout`. This way the timer will stop when there is nothing more to do - otherwise the timer will run in the background unnecessary.

For a very smooth animation you could replace the `setTimeout` it with `requestAnimationFrame` and use lower step value for `i`:

### [Demo using rAF](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/eDA9d/)

```
var i = 0;
var step = 0.01;  // lower value

(function init() {

    // ... rest of code identical
    
    if (i <= 2 * Math.PI) requestAnimationFrame(init);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for comment and fast answer but I want something different like in this image http://i58.tinypic.com/t8q4vk.png

When circle is fully loaded i want to looks like this image

I'll try to explain again.Circle loader start.First 25 % of the circle are red then after this 25% we start with blue.When circle is at 50% we start with red again and when circle is at 75% we start with blue again